# Linux (ArchLinux), capture window content or run external program inside a window

Tags: linux, graphics, archlinux

I don't know at all how to formulate that.

I would to make a program able to add visual effect on external programs chosen (like an overlay). I don't use a desktop environment like gnome, kde, xfce... (if possible i prefer staying like that) i will use xinit, or perhaps it will such a "desktop" environment. I want to make something very light to let the maximum of resources on the programs launched.

I thought also, it must let the mouse action accross, except for some areas.

I don't know where to begin, i just wrote some programs in Python, i thought to use C/C++, i have a lack of documentation.

Thank by advance.

I tried nothing for the while, i would to know which language use and tracks.

I read links suggested by StackOverFlow, perhaps the one about QT are interesting but i worked with QT and it's not a lightweight (there is few years). I use ArchLinux to have something very light, this program must go in the same way.